# EntityFrameworkCore AddOrUpdate

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework-core, .net-5, upsert

I want to add or update entities in EFCore 5.
Currently I am using Context.Find to determine whether to update or to add. I want this logic to be very performant and I see that much of cpu time is spent on the Find method (database call). I would like to move the logic of determining add or update to be evaluated by the database once SaveChanges is called. I would like to be able to specify which properties have changed and which should be used by the possibly already existing entity (or initialized with default values). I guess this can be done with Context.Entry(...).Property(...).IsModified.

I still want to be able to use the DbContext change tracking, multiple add or update calls should be combined, custom queries are not possible.
Primary keys are defined and not auto generated.

Is there any way to achieve this with EntityFrameworkCore?

There is/was IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate but I think it is not available in current release? Also I think it is not recommended to use outside of migrations/seeding. Moreover I think it does not work as I guess it would overwrite existing values with default values of the changed entity (unchanged values should not be overwritten to default values, I am not recreating the complete entity on upsert, thats why I would like to specify which properties have changed).

Comment: just call a stored procedure that performs an upsert?

Comment: @MortenBork This will not affect the change tracking right? I want to cache data and call savechanges after many changes have been made. Thats why I would like have a functional change tracking.

Comment: It will in the sense that the stored procedure will make a change, and if your context is trying to apply a change after the store procedure has executed, an existing object was updated, that you have a reference to, then that object will be "un-synchronized". However, as long as it isn't marked as "altered", the save changes should remain un-affected. However, there is a potential, depending on what you have implemented code wise. 

If you have followed a repository pattern. Then there should be no issue

Comment: if your DB is mysql, there is a very nice "if key exist, then update, else insert" that is the most efficient way to do it. 
If your DB is MS-sql, then there almost no difference between what entity framework does and what the DB does, in terms of making an upsert.

MSSql -> Dated example, but still true: https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3739131/UPSERT-Functionality-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm

Mysql: 
https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: I know it is possible by writing SQL directly. My goal was to use EF and the most important part is that the query should be executed ONLY on SaveChanges (where maybe 30 entities are Added and 100 have been changed, queries to the database should only be made on SaveChanges for both of them).
The stored procedure would be fine when used in SaveChanges (or maybe as Interceptor?) but the main goal is to get rid of the database query as I dont care if it is added or modified (and with set primary keys, the data shouldnt depend on this information aswell).